# Pass a list of POJO items to a stored procedure via myBatis?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, mybatis

This is probably a dumb question - and I did google it quite a bit, and didn't find really anything that (I personally) was able to get working - I think I need a little bit more guidance.

I have the following mapping xml...

```
  <select id="deleteItems" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    exec [dbo].[PR_ItemsForDeletion_Delete]
  </select>
```

Now, we can ignore the result map here I believe - because I am not concerned with what I am getting back (yet!)

Now, see that stored procedure? I didn't write it - and I also don't have access to the code for that - but I do know for a fact that it works.

The stored procedure takes a list of items. I need to pass in the following :

```
List<CustomDeletableObject>
```

Trusting that the sproc works, and with the mapper I just want to execute that mapping XML - and pass a list to it, but I have ABSOLUTELY no idea where to begin with that.

Massive thankyou in advance, I have been banging my head against this one for hours now.

EDIT for further clarity :

The custom deletable object type contains two properties :

private long id - which is just an id we use.
private Sting token - the data we are actually storing.

the Stored procedure, I don't have access to the query itself - but essentially what it does, is deletes every item in a table which has a match to an item in the list we want to provide to it via myBatis.

This is how I am planning to call the mapper...

```
@Override
public boolean deleteItems(List<CustomDeletableObject> tokens){

    // This method handles the deletion.
    jobMapper.deleteItems();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: amend your question with stored procedure signature (parameters type) and properties of `CustomDeletableObject` that will be passed

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean, sorry! I am still not very good at working with myBatis, trying to learn as I go - :(

Comment: what are the parameters (what type) of the stored procedure? What are the properties of the class CustomDeletableObject? Do you know them ? Don't be sorry, I was just asking you to provide these info required to answer your question.

Comment: The list contains instances of type "Token" Which is a pojo, and it contains a (long) property named "id" and a String, which is the actual representaion of the data, and that is named "token"

Comment: Does that help? or do you need more info? Sorry for the beginner level questions here!

Comment: You will never be blamed for asking question. But you will likely have more helpful answers if your question is good and contains all required info so that your situation and your objective are clear for any reader.

Comment: You tell about a stored procedure, now you shall tell everything you know about it, especially about its parameters.

Comment: and by the way, for every new info you provide, you shall edit your question to improve it with this new info.... you did it pretty well for your other question I have answered lately

Comment: Hey @blackwizard - I will provide more information in the morning - I got dragged away from this issue today because I needed to leave work - My aunt died. I will update soon and maybe we can get this working :)

Comment: Hey @blackwizard : I updated the question with some more information - Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: from Java/Mybatis side, the details of what the stored procedure does are not needed. But, to call it, it behaves just like an API, it requires to know its  name and the types of the parameters. The java/Mybatis code to do depends on that because java->SQL types mapping has to be done.

Comment: The name of the list (within the sproc) is named @pTokenList the name of the sproc is dbo.PR_removeTokens.sql

Comment: and the most important: the (SQL /t-SQL) type ?? and its definition if it is a complex/custom type.

Comment: We are using a jtds sql database (I believe that means it is oracle, right?)

Comment: [TDS is an open source 100% pure Java (type 4) JDBC 3.0 driver for Microsoft SQL Server](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: ah ok - do we have enough information in order to maybe see if we can get this working? Or do I need to keep searching for more info?

Comment: indeed, we need more info: the stored procedure parameters type. you need same info to call a java method. Do you see my point or not?

Comment: You mean like, the method within the java interface class, and the parameters within that?

Comment: Added an edit which shows the interface! :)

Comment: No. With the info I have so far the stored procedure is declared as follow: PR_removeTokens(pTokenList IN **SQL_or_TSQL_type_we need_to_know**)  => what is this type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137378/discussion-between-mickeythreesheds-and-blackwizard).

Comment: I left some messages in the chat - @blackwizard - I am not too sure what you mean when you ask for the type...